# How to put more information on my R Pie Chart ?

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have the following simple R code.

```
vect <- c(a = 4, b = 7, c = 5)
pie(vect, labels = c("A", "B", "C"), col = c("#999999", "#6F6F6F", "#000000"))
```

that print the following pie chart

[image]

How do I modify the above code to print more detail on my pie chart, so that it look like this other one ?

[image]

Thanks for any reply !

Comment: That image reminds me of [ggplot2's `coord_polar`](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_polar.html)

Comment: Your pie chart needs more dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956582/how-to-put-more-information-on-my-r-pie-chart#comment14303146_10956582) in details:

1. Create a dummy data frame for the example:

   ```
   vect <- data.frame(v=c(rep('a', 25), rep('b', 30), rep('c', 45)))
   ```
2. Call `ggplot` for a pie-chart (`coord_polar`) based on the [manual](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_polar.html):

   ```
   p <- ggplot(vect, aes(x=factor(1), fill = factor(v))) + geom_bar(width = 1) + coord_polar(theta="y")
   ```
3. Tweak it:

   ```
   p + opts(title = "Decision tree") + xlab('') + ylab('') + 
   theme_bw() + scale_fill_grey(name = "Rankings")
   ```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend several attributes you dive into with the plot method. For the plot title, see `main` attribute, and `legend` attribute for adding the colorful palette.

You may also refer to a simple plot tutorial here: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/#piecharts

Comment: @FopaLéonConstantin I will be more happy when you vote up for, even accept, my answers ! :-p